# How to prevent a shared preference from being clear in setting

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I don't want to let Settings clear my app `sharedPreference` by anyone: is it possible?

Comment: I found another way, check my edit.

Comment: but i don't want to keep database on remote server! instead i want to prevent clearing sharedPref. thanks for ans..

Comment: Understand, there is only one answer: is not possible ;-) .

Comment: i found a way to prevent data being cleared from shared preference...See My Answer ::)))

Answer (score 3):

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926482/is-it-possible-to-block-shared-preferences-to-avoid-being-deleted):

> Shared preferences and files not saved to the SD card will be deleted
>   when the app is uninstalled.
>
> Files saved to the SD card will persists after uninstall, however, the
>   user will have access to read, over-write, and delete these files at
>   will.
>
> If you need truly permanent storage the best way forward would be to
>   store the data remotely on a server that you control.

If you don't care about data, then you can save it on SD Card.

**EDIT**

I think that BFil answer's is very good on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108787/android-save-file-permanently-even-after-clear-data-uninstall), check it.

**My final verdict**

After long research (for my pure and insane curiosity!), there is no way (at the moment?) to preserve `SharedPreference` after clear on *Settings*: the only way is a server vault or [Data Backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html).

Comment: i found a way to prevent data being cleared from shared preference...See My Answer ::)))

Answer (score 0):

add this tag in manifesto allowClearUserData=false. this code verified.